# Selecting top two features with longest length in the line vector file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, length, select-by-expression, qgis-expression

I have a line vector file and I need to select two lines with the longest length using expression. I am familiar with selecting the line with the longest length:

```
length($geometry) = maximum(length($geometry))
```

[image]

But how to select the longest and second-longest line using an expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
$length >= array_sort(array_agg($length), 0)[1]
```

---

**Explanation**

1. Create an array of the length of each line with [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg) and [`$length`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#length)
2. Sort the value by a length with [`array_sort()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-sort) with the ascending parameter set to `0` (false), thus ordering in descending order
3. Get the second element (second longest line): as array-index starts with 0 for the first element, use the [index operator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-index) `[1]`
4. Check if the current feature's length (`$length`) is equal or longer (`>=`) than this second-longest line